# How do I add a custom "monero:…" URL handler to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How do I add a custom URL handler to Firefox so the browser opens a Monero wallet when I click a `monero:…` URL?

Adding a boolean `network.protocol-handler.expose.monero` to true in `about:config` didn't work.

Comment: @TobyKelsey What am I missing? Why doesn't adding a boolean `network.protocol-handler.expose.monero` to true work for me?